# Notify-osd stopped functioning

Tags: ubuntu-11.10, notify-osd

I have reloaded, reinstalled, tried NotifyOSDconfiguration and get nothing to appear.  I am running 11.10 ubuntu with conky on the desktop.  ANy ideas?